# MySQL, alternative to using IN which will prioisties the first value?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to use the `IN` function (in my php script) e.g.

```
WHERE Keywords.Word IN ('$search[0]','$search[1]',...)
```

However, the first word I used was unique in the database and the second was a very popular word. It hasn't shown any result for the first word. I have LIMIT 100 on the end.

Ideally I don't want to use an `AND` as this would limit results, so `OR` seems best, I'm just surprised it didn't rate the first value higher than others.

What can I do ?

Comment: BTW, I hope that every item within `$search` gets properly escaped before being injected into your SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is merging with the LIMIT clause.  You want it to perform well, so you need to get at most 100 from any branch.  A naive approach of ranking all rows by using CASE / IF will cause a full table scan.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 as prec, column-list FROM table-list
    WHERE Keywords.Word = '$search[0]'
    LIMIT 100) A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 2 as prec, column-list FROM table-list
    WHERE Keywords.Word = '$search[1]'
    LIMIT 100) B
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 3 as prec, column-list FROM table-list
    WHERE Keywords.Word = '$search[2]'
    LIMIT 100) C
ORDER BY prec
LIMIT 100;
```

This could work better for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,if(word = 'some word',1,2) as relevance
from table
where word in ('some word','other word','another')
order by relevance
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can just sort results to your liking:

```
SELECT Keywords.KeywordsId, Keywords.Word
FROM Keywords
WHERE Keywords.Word IN ('foo', 'bar')
ORDER BY
CASE Keywords.Word 

    WHEN 'foo' THEN 1
    ELSE 2

END,
Keywords.Word -- Or any other criteria
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE Keywords.Word
WHEN '$search[0]' THEN 1
WHEN '$search[1]' THEN 2
-- ...
ELSE 999
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
WHERE Keywords.Word IN ('$search[0]','$search[1]',...)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(Keywords.Word,'$search[0],$search[1],...')
```

There is a limitation, though, that your search terms cannot contain commas.  If that's a limitation you can live with, then this is the way to go.

Comment: Thats doesn't seem to doing what you say, my first word doesn't appear. ?

Comment: @Jules Check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to make sure you're using the function properly... and if it's not doing what the documentation says, then you should file a bug report!